# "Barcode" reading from scanned image

Tags: image, image-processing, processing, barcode

I want to read a barcode from a scanned image that I printed. The image format is not relevant. I found that the scanned images are of very low quality and can understand why it normal barcodes fail.

My idea is to create a non standard and very simple barcode at the top of each page printed. It will be `20 squares` in a row forming a simple binary code.`Filled = 1, open = 0`. It will be large enough on a`A4` to make detection easy.

At this stage I need to load the image and find the barcode somewhere at the top. It will not be exactly at the same spot as it is scanned in. Step into each block and build the ID.

Any knowledge or links to info would be awesome.

Comment: The [processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: Don't use a non-standard bar code, just take a standard one and scale it up so that it's large enough to not get mangled by your scanner.

Comment: That is one idea I can try. @MarkRansom . I want to send customers a letter and need them to sign, scan and send it back. If i upscale the barcode, it might end up being on its own page.

Comment: I was able to create a simple binary barcode. Once scanned I could do edge detection to get rid of most of the noise. My thinking was that my barcode is 3x higher than any of the text on the page if i find a line of that lenght i can assume that is where the barcode starts. It works pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can preset a region of interest that contains the code and nothing else, then detection is pretty easy. Scan a few rays across this region and find the white/black and black/white transitions. Then, knowing where the "cells" should be, you known their polarity.

For this to work, you need to frame your cells with two black ones on both ends to make sure to know where it starts/stops (if the scale is fixed, you can do with just a start cell, but I would not recommend this).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at https://github.com/zxing/zxing. I would suggest to use a 1D bar code, but wide enough to match the low resolution of the scanner.

You could also invent your own bar code encoding and try to parse it your self. Use thick bars for 1 and thin lines for 0. A thick bar would be for instance 2 white pixels, 4 black pixels. A thin line would be 2 white pixels, 2 black pixels and 2 white pixels. The last two pixels encode the bit value. 
The pixel should be the size of the scanned image pixel.

You then process the image scan line by scan line, trying to locate the bar code.

We locate the bar code by comparing a given pixel value sequence with a pattern. This is performed by computing a score function. The sum of squared difference is a good pick. When computing the score we ignore the two pixels encoding the bit value.

When the score is below a threshold, we found a matching pattern. It is good to add parity bits to the encoded value so that it's validity can be checked.

Computing a sum of square on a sliding window can be optimized.